# Can't do wbadmin backup

Tags: windows, backup

In Windows 10 I can't do a Windows backup, here what I got:

```
wbadmin start backup -backupTarget:\\192.168.188.1\Backup\ -include:C:,D:,E:,F: -allCritical -quiet
wbadmin 1.0 - Backup command-line tool
(C) Copyright 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Note: The backed up data cannot be securely protected at this destination.
Backups stored on a remote shared folder might be accessible by other
people on the network. You should only save your backups to a location
where you trust the other users who have access to the location or on a
network that has additional security precautions in place.

Retrieving volume information...
This will back up (EFI System Partition),Download(D:),Utils(E:),Doc(F:),System(C:),Recovery (450.00 MB)
to \\192.168.188.1\Backup\.
The server threw an exception.
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

In C:\Windows\Logs\WindowsBackup nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

- No event log entries
- No errors or warnings in `C:\Windows\Logs\WindowsBackup`

Here is what worked for me:

1. Delete the directory `WindowsImageBackup` on the target drive
2. Run the following command on an elevated command prompt (administrative privileges):

```
wbadmin delete catalog
```

After that the following command backed up as expected:

```
wbadmin start backup -backupTarget:Z: -include:C: -allCritical -quiet
```

Comment: `wbadmin delete catalog` did it for me.  I had the problem after an upgrade to Windows 10